# Watch a Facebook video in slow motion

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

With its JavaScript API it is not difficult to get a YouTube video in a Web page by giving its YouTube id. Then the user can watch it in slow motion if they want.

How can I do the same with Facebook videos? I can't find how to do it with graph APi or with other APIs. I am inexperienced with Facebook APIs.

Do I need a special permission to download a Facebook video in one Web page I have written (the user type the id of the video and then can watch it in the page)?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. If you want to embed a Facebook video on an external page, you can use the [Embedded Video Player](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/) social plugin. (Whether or not that will allow the user to watch in slow motion, I don’t know – or if Facebook’s player does even support that.)

Comment: Thanks for the reference but it seems it is not possible to watch a video in slow motion with tis plugin or do things like with the YouTube API. For example with the JavaScript YouTube API you can choose the playback rate (player.setPlaybackRate(..)) or get/set the current time in the video (player.getCurrentTime(), seekToMoment(...)). With this API you can mark a moment in the video and return to it latter, and other things of this type. I would like to do the same with Facebook videos.

Comment: There is no API to that plugin, nor any other player or API to play Facebook videos.

Comment: Thanks for the information.